# AutoDisposeFamilyAsyncNotifierProvider error

Tags: flutter, dart

I got this following error in Riverpod v2 without riverpod_generator. Since there are not many articles about FamilyProvider, I am stack of this error for few weeks.

```dart
_TypeError (type '(() => Y0, {required String? name, required Iterable<ProviderOrFamily>? dependencies, required Iterable<ProviderOrFamily>? allTransitiveDependencies, required (() => String)? debugGetCreateSourceHash, Family<Object?>? from, Object? argument}) => AutoDisposeFamilyAsyncNotifierProviderImpl<ProjectDetailController, ProjectDetailModel, int>' is not a subtype of type '(() => ProjectDetailController, {required Set<ProviderOrFamily>? allTransitiveDependencies, Object? argument, required (() => String)? debugGetCreateSourceHash, required Iterable<ProviderOrFamily>? dependencies, Family<Object?> from, required String? name}) => AutoDisposeFamilyAsyncNotifierProviderImpl<ProjectDetailController, ProjectDetailModel, int>' of 'function result')
```

Comment: Show code.  Class or function generator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is due to Dart sdk error.
It will be fixed in Dart3.
https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/issues/1733

In my opinion, using riverpod generator is much safer.